# show list of articles or a button

Tags: android

this is a very basic question, as I am just beginning with Android.

When I click a button I want to show a list of articles saved on my device and the user can choose one of them. BUT if there aren't any, I want to show a "Download" button to allow user to download the articles.
I don't know how to do the layouts - should I call a new `activityForResult` with a `ListActivity` intent ? but then, in case there are no articles, how will I show the button?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like very basic, I think you have to go through some basic tutorials for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you brief idea.Then you will have to try to implement it using references on internet.If you will come to a problem,we all are happy to help you,but at least you should put some efforts in coding.

So you will have to have a button,a listview and another button in xml layout.

A button (say **btn_ShowArticles**) is for its click to populate the listview.

A listview (say **articleList**) is for showing list of articles.

another button (say **btn_download**) is to let user download articles if there aren't found any.

Now you will have to catch button click of **btn_ShowArticles** and there,you will have to fill the listview using an adapter.

you can check if the adapter is null or not.If it is null then you can show **btn_Download** and set listview invisible.

Else you can set **btn_Download** invisible and populate listview.

You can code to download the article in on click of **btn_Download**.